# Add new row using JavaScript to gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view. I dynamically add new row using JS, in the GV an image(addButton) in each row, while clicking that image the following js will be called.

```
function AddNewRecord(e) {

    debugger;
    var hfFirstNewf = document.getElementById('ctl14_hfFirstNewf');
    var grd = document.getElementById('ctl14_gvWTM');
    var rowCount = grd.rows.length;
    var tbod = grd.rows[0].parentNode;
    var **newRow** = grd.rows[grd.rows.length - 1].cloneNode(true);
    tbod.appendChild(newRow);

    return false;
}
```

while debugging through the code the **newRow.innerHTML** contains the following (which is a part of the original code)

```
<SPAN style="WIDTH: 100%; DISPLAY: inline-block" id=ctl14_gvWTM_ctl02_lblSrno>1</SPAN> <INPUT style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: 15px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" id=ctl14_gvWTM_ctl02_btnADD class=href title="Add another Row" onclick="return AddNew();" src="http://localhost:12294/RIBO/App_Themes/RIBO/Images/AddNew.png" type=image name=ctl14$gvWTM$ctl02$btnADD Text="ADD">
```

here `**id=ctl14_gvWTM_ctl02_btnADD**` ctl02 is the ID for all the new rows generated(when i click second row **addButton** of the grid.When click 3rd row **addButton** it will be **id=ctl14_gvWTM_ctl03_btnADD** for the third row and the new row).
Problem is while clicking the new row it operates based on the original row(row2 or row3).

Is there any solution for this? 
`or` can I change `innerText` text  **ctl02** into something new for the new rows while generating by using `replace`  ??

[image: )]

[image]

`from image1` , I have added new row using that plus image.all the three rows are newly added from first row.While click gridview's  4th row `DUnumber` column(`you can find the cursor at the bottom round`) it displays 1st row's Suggestion(process symbol on top round
`image 2 :` loaded suggestion for 1st row DuNumber while click on 4th row DuNumber.When select anything from that it will loaded on row1 instead of row 4

Comment: Its not clear why you are generating ids? Anyway, I don't get your goal. So once if you add a new row by javascript, then what?

Comment: @deostaroll I'm not generating ids. I have usercontrols inside the grid(i.m not providing here) .While clicking on the usercontrol it will display a suggestion table we can select option from that suggestion.While clicking the new row (after generated using  that Js), it will pop up the old row(from which the nwe row gwnerated) suggestion.when selecting options from that suggestion it will set to the old row instead of new row.

Comment: @@deostroll When i debug through the javascript it give the old row id(inner text) for the new row also.

Comment: You may need to post more code here in order for us to replicate and understand the issue. Alternatively, you can post a series of screenshots describing your problem. Its difficult to understand the problem you've mentioned above with few details.

Comment: @deostroll now added screenshot of my problem.Please help me

Comment: Ok, is the textbox DuNumber the so said usercontrol?

Comment: the textbox combined with thw suggestion box is the usercontrol

Comment: So let me get this straight so I can make an app similar to yours at my end. User control consists of a textbox, and some sort of a ajax control toolkit modal panel, is it so?

Comment: yes just like that of my control

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to do.

## User control design

- You need to [embed javascript](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-asp-net-server-controls-with-embedded-javascript) along with the user control. The javascript in that will be the function you are calling to update data from that popup to the concerned textbox.
- Issue you are facing is that you script is setting the wrong textbox.

One technique suggested here is to wrap all stuff into a div. So you your user control markup would have:

```
<div>
   <asp:TextBox ID="tbx1" runat="server" ...></asp:TextBox>
   <%-- other stuff --%>
</div>
```

Assume there is a button in there somewhere in the code above (and for simplicity sakes assume there are no more nested divs). When you click it, you need the reference to the button. For this modify the javascript function as follows:

```
function AddNewRecord(ctrl) {

    var divContainer = ctrl.parentNode; // reference to the containing div.     
    //to get textbox
    var inputFields = divContainer.getElementsByTagName('input');
    //usually it would be the first one...
    var tbx = inputFields[0];
    console.log(tbx.value); //prints value of textbox.

}
```

And the function is invoked as follows:

```
<input type="button" onclick="AddNewRecord(this)" ... />
```

Comment: All you have said were already done.problem is the clientId of the copied new row controls and the source row controls both are having same ID so the select value will fix in source row control

Comment: So are you adding new row via js...?

Comment: But recommended way to add new row to the gridview is to do it completely server-side. We usually use a datatable, store that into viewstate, and add new row to that, then bind that to the gridview... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467788/Dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-from-ASP-NET